# Dismiss to other storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

In my project i have 2 storyboards. One for login and one for the main.
After login is complete i present the main storyboard using this method:

```
    -(void)successLogin {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My question is how do I get back to the login storyboard if i want to put logout button in the main storyboard. I tried doing the following:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why you not put  your login VC to main stroyboard? Means everything in one storyboard. You should use one storyboard for every VC and use navigation controller to push and pop view.

Comment: It does not make sense to use multiple Storyboard in your case. Just use single storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try this on LOGOUT click event:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

 LoginviewController *Login = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginviewController"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:Login animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set one view controller as root view controller then present another view controller.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:viewController];

[viewController presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you will come to the rootViewController when you **dismissViewControllerAnimated:**

Answer (score 0):

logout success
Try this code it works for you

```
-(void)successlogout
{
    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    login *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```